# Caddy reverse proxy to /dir/ to localnet:port

Tags: directory, port, reverse-proxy, caddy

I got Caddy from official repo on docker hub all up and running with automatic https on several subdomains. So far so good.

```
sub1.domain.com {
    respond "Test"
}

https://sub1.domain.com:3333 {
    reverse_proxy 192.168.7.6:3000
}


https://sub1.domain.com:4444 {
    reverse_proxy 192.168.7.6:4000
}

sub2.domain.com {
    respond "Test"
}
```

There are two things I do not understand.

1) I would rather have the proxy working on subdirs forwarding to ports, but this fails, as the dir seems to be maintained as well while proxying. Example:

```
https://sub1.domain.com:4444 {
    reverse_proxy /dir/ 192.168.7.6:4000
}
```

So eventually I end up at 192.168.7.6:4000/dir/ instead of only 192.168.7.6:4000

2) When I call sub2.domain.com combined with a port from sub1 it shows a blank page (source empty as well). So for example sub2.domain.com:4444. I would rather expect a timeout or error page?

Many thanks for hints and suggestions in advance!

Comment: Take a look at https://caddyserver.com/v1/docs/proxy, and the "without" configuration key it seems related to what you're trying to archive

Comment: @papey That's for v1, OP is using v2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matching requests does not rewrite them. So, matching on `/dir/` does not change the URI of the request. It's simply a filter.

To strip a path prefix, you can do:

```
uri strip_prefix /dir
```

Since this is pretty common, there's some work to make this even easier in the future: https://github.com/caddyserver/caddy/pull/3281

For more help, feel free to ask on our forums, the audience there is much better targeted for Caddy users: https://caddy.community

Comment: Could you please show a full working example of this? It's kinda frustrating that in the Caddy community everything is always supposedly super simple, but then there are never examples of what an actual working configuration might look like.